# Do I need reverse proxy like nginx for Azure web app service?

Tags: azure, nginx

This is a very basic question, but I couldn't find a clear answer.

So, normally a reverse proxy should stand before web servers (i.e. expressjs).
But most Azure Web App Service examples don't consider reverse proxy.

So, are there some functions in Azure Web Service that act as a reverse proxy?

Or do we still have to add a reverse proxy? If so, could you point out a good example?
Azure Web App Service only supports a single container, but a common way is to put a reverse proxy and a web server in separate containers.

Comment: Any function app can define an endpoint that serves as Reverse Proxy for another API.

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT Azure functions and web app service are different. Could you clarify what you meant? Or what you meant is that it is possible to use Azure Functions as a reverse proxy?

Comment: Yes, you can.Azure Function Proxies are quite similar to Azure API management.  Please refer [Reverse Proxy Using Azure Functions Proxies](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reverse-proxy-using-azure-functions-proxies/)

Comment: Also refer [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/43630/azure-web-app-to-act-as-a-of-reverse-proxy-with-a.html)